# Android getting assigned alternative IP even though already has one reserved

Tags: ip, iptables, dhcp

Within my network, I have an android device that I have reserved an IP address for, but after rebooting the device a new IP has been assigned.

[image]

the names are identical so unsure why this would happen?

Comment: What is the reservation based on – MAC address? (I've seen some Android firmwares which randomize it.)

Comment: yes thats correct a MAC address